# whitenoise dosen't seem to work in Django

Tags: django, static, whitenoise

I want to check my web app in `DEBUG = False` and use whitenoise to do the static stuff. I have followed documentation and different blog post, I have also used the tool before, but this time it just does not work.

**Things I've tried:**

1. reinstalling whitenoise
2. changing the location of whitenoise middleware
3. collected statics many times and also changed its name
4. restart the local web server

**settings.py:**

```
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
]

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / "static"
```

**urls.py:**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('bella_beauty_shop_web_store.urls')),
    path('123321/', admin.site.urls),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

and here you can see that I have collected statics:
[image]

**Errors:**
When I put the `DEBUG` to `FALSE`, there is an error in the console:
[image]

I really don't know what's wrong here. I am quit new to Django, but I have built some web apps and also used whitenoise before.

As you know, I expect my html to render with style when the `DEBUG` is set to `FALSE` using whitenoise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yeah finally I've found the problem. I was using the wrong form of adding static files in templates, like a syntax error but doesn't really rises any error.

Instead of this `src: url('../fonts/iran-sans/IRANSans-Medium.woff') format('woff');` I changed it to this `src: url('fonts/iran-sans/IRANSans-Medium.woff') format('woff');`

Instead of this `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href={% static 'style-index.css' %}/>` I changed it to this `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'style-index.css' %}"/>` -> if you pay a close look you can see that in the first one I used `href=`, though in the second one I used `href=""`.

It looks kinda stupid but when the DEBUG is True, the first ones work great.

Answer (score 0):

As per [documentation](https://whitenoise.readthedocs.io/en/latest/django.html), place the middleware right after `SecurityMiddleware`.

Comment: I have tried putting it right after SecurityMiddleware, but it didn't work.